# How to Display Current location on tableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, google-maps

I want to Display current location Address on a `TableViewCell`. I got the latitude and longitude but i can't understand how to show address string on cell.

i wrote the below code in `ViewDidLoad()` 
it display the address in label.

```
let manager: CLLocationManager = locationManager
  CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

let placemark = placemarks?[0]

let lines = placemark?.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"]

let addressString = (lines as! NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "\n")

self.lblAddress.text = addressString

print(addressString)

})


but i want to show the address on tableview Cell.

 //return cell for perticular row withing section

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if indexPath.section <= 1
    {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(self.batteryLevel() * 100) %"

        return cell
     }

     else

     {

          //create reusable cell object by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

          //identifier must register with cell

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LocationTableViewCellRID", for: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell

         let personName = txtFieldName.text

         let a = LocationVC()

         cell.lblName?.text = "\(personName) \(self.batteryLevel() * 100) %"

         cell.lblAddress?.text = 

         return cell
     }
}
```

I want to show the address on lblAddress. I am new to iOS. Thanks in Advance for you help.

Comment: Are you able to get location address from Lat-lon? If yes then create an string (say addressString) object that holds address & in cellforRowAtIndexPath cell.lblAddress?.text = addressString

Comment: I already try that but found error that "Use of unresolved identifier 'addressString'"

Comment: Where you declare your String?

Comment: in ViewDidLoad. you can see addressString in the above code

Comment: ohhh...you have to declare string in your class not in any function. Add string above the viewdidload as var addressString = String()

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have declared a property for `addressString` above the `viewDidLoad` method. Not inside the `viewDidLoad` method.

Add this above the `viewDidLoad` method

```
let addressString = String()
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` method change this line

```
let addressString = (lines as! NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "\n")
```

to

```
self.addressString = (lines as! NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `addressString` a property, you would have access to it in `cellRowForAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I already try that but found error that "Use of unresolved identifier 'addressString'"